# TypeScript function is not firing on .net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I created an Asp.Net Core MVC application and I was trying to play around with TypeScript. I created a .ts file and add the following line.

(() => { alert("Made with TypeScript"); })();

According to the example this suppose to show an message dialog on the page load. 
When I build the project it successfully created the .js file according to the TypeScript config file and I have already added the resulting .js file in the HTML page.
But when I run the program and visit the corresponding page I don't get the message dialog.
I tried couple of examples but the result was same.

My environment:
Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition
.Net Core 1.1.1

File Structure:

[image]

View:

[image]

Startup.cs

[image]

**NOTE:**
I added a plain .html page (without using .cshtml) and included the .js file which compiled by .ts and it works! I think the problem is with the MVC view.

Answer (score 1):

You should put any served static files in the **wwwroot** folder of your web application. Anything outside of this folder is not accessible for webclients.

When you call `~/scripts/appscript1.js` you are really referring to a file that should be in `wwwroot/script/appscript1.js`, so try copying the resulting .js file there.

wwwroot is also called the "web root" folder, while the project directory seen in visual studio is called the "content root".

- See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files for more information
- To prevent always having to manually copy static files from your project structure to the wwwroot folder, consider using a task runner (Grunt, Gulp) or packager (Webpack) to do this for you.